# How to implement minDimensions in Uploadcare Widget

Tags: uploadcare

Settings can be added to Uploadcare as follows:

```
var myDialog = uploadcare.openDialog(null, {
    imagesOnly: true,
    multiple: true,
    multipleMin: 1
    multipleMax: 7
});
```

Now how is `minDimensions` being set? [The documentation](https://uploadcare.com/docs/api_reference/javascript/file_validation/) shows `minDimensions(800x600)` but that notation doesn't work. The below attempt does not work:

```
var myDialog = uploadcare.openDialog(null, {
    imagesOnly: true,
    multiple: true,
    multipleMin: 1
    multipleMax: 7,
    minDimensions: '800,600'
});
```

Following doesn't work either:

```
var myDialog = uploadcare.openDialog(null, {
    imagesOnly: true,
    multiple: true,
    multipleMin: 1
    multipleMax: 7,
    minWidth: 800,
    minHeight: 600
});
```

Additionally, it's unclear what happens if an uploaded image dimenions is less than these settings. Does the Widget show an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*minDimensions*, as well as *minWidth* and *minHeight*, are not widget options. The link refers to file validation docs. File validation is a function that invokes before the file is completely uploaded, and have access to the fileInfo object so that you can check file parameters (size, name, image dimensions, etc.) and abort uploading if some parameter doesn't match your requirements.

To set an image dimension validator, you'd need to define a validation function first

```
function minDimensions(width, height) {
  return function(fileInfo) {
    var imageInfo = fileInfo.originalImageInfo;
    if (imageInfo !== null) {
      if (imageInfo.width < width || imageInfo.height < height) {
        throw new Error('dimensions');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when you open a dialog, you add the validation function to the validators array in the dialog settings

```
var myDialog = uploadcare.openDialog(null, {
    imagesOnly: true,
    multiple: true,
    multipleMin: 1,
    multipleMax: 7,
    validators: [minDimensions(800, 600)]
});
```

If a file doesn't pass the validation, the widget will show the default error message - "Can't upload", but you can customize the error message using the UPLOADCARE_LOCALE_TRANSLATIONS option

```
UPLOADCARE_LOCALE_TRANSLATIONS = {
  // messages for widget
  errors: {
    'dimensions': 'The image has to be 800x600px or larger.'
  },
  // messages for dialog’s error page
  dialog: { tabs: { preview: { error: {
    'dimensions': {
      title: 'Error.',
      text: 'The image is too small. Try to upload another one.',
      back: 'Back'
    }
  } } } }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, appreciated!

Comment: Little detail: I guess dimensions should be written without quotes?

Comment: Also, for the sake of completeness, the function minDimension misses an 's' in above code.

Comment: @bart thanks, I've corrected the name of the function. In the `throw new Error('dimensions')` and in the `UPLOADCARE_LOCALE_TRANSLATIONS` `dimensions` should be written within quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your own validator functions and add them to widget/dialog.
So, write `minDimensions` function with signature and logic of your choice.
The docs have example implementation for `imagesOnly` and `maxDimenstions` validation functions. You can use them for inspiration.

When your validation function rejects a file for some reason, you should throw Error, e.g. `throw new Error('dimensions');`
The `'dimensions'` string will be used to look for a user friendly message in your custom localisation map:

```
UPLOADCARE_LOCALE_TRANSLATIONS = {
  errors: {
    'dimensions': 'File dimension check failed',
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

You can find more elaborate examples [here](https://uploadcare.com/docs/uploads/widget/validation/).